# Exoplayer with preroll and dynamic ad insertion

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, preroll

I want to make work my DASH stream with preroll and DAI. For now, I was able to make: DASH + preroll working and DASH + dai. But all three not

dash + dai :

```
val dashMediaSource = DashMediaSource.Factory(dashChunkSourceFactory, manifestDataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(
                MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri(Uri.parse(URLDAI))  //diff
                    .setDrmConfiguration(
                        MediaItem.DrmConfiguration.Builder(drmSchemeUuid)
                            .setLicenseUri(DRM_LICENSE_URL).build()
                    )
                    .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MPD)
                    .setTag(null)
                    .build()
            )

  playerView.setMediaSource(adsMediaSource)
    playerView.prepare()
```

dash + preroll

```
val dashMediaSource = DashMediaSource.Factory(dashChunkSourceFactory, manifestDataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(
                MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri(Uri.parse(URL))  //diff
                    .setDrmConfiguration(
                        MediaItem.DrmConfiguration.Builder(drmSchemeUuid)
                            .setLicenseUri(DRM_LICENSE_URL).build()
                    )
                    .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MPD)
                    .setTag(null)
                    .build()
            )

val dataSpec = DataSpec(Uri.parse(PREROLL))
val imaSdkSettings = ImaSdkFactory.getInstance().createImaSdkSettings()
val imaAdsLoader = ImaAdsLoader.Builder(this).setImaSdkSettings(imaSdkSettings).build()
imaAdsLoader.setPlayer(playerView)
val adsMediaSource = AdsMediaSource(mediaSource, dataSpec, 0, DefaultMediaSourceFactory(this), imaAdsLoader, binding.playerView)
playerView.setMediaSource(adsMediaSource)
playerView.prepare()
```

But if I combine both I get :

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$UnexpectedLoaderException: Unexpected IllegalArgumentException: null
```

How can I have all three workings: preroll + dai + dash ( drm widevine) in exoplayer 2.18.1?

Thanks

Comment: did you fix your problem

Comment: no. i did not find a solutin

Answer (score 0):

It might not like the `.setTag(null)` part; either remove that or provide `String`.

And I also find it strange that you access `playerView` ...and not `player`; for comparison:

```
player.setMediaSource(adsMediaSource)
player.prepare()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. They stated it here:
[https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer/ad-insertion#:~:text=.release()-,Note,-%3A%20Currently%20only](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer/ad-insertion#:%7E:text=.release()-,Note,-%3A%20Currently%20only)

These stream types are incompatible but you still can combine the features:

```kotlin
val imaAdsMediaSource = AdsMediaSource(
    mediaSource, // original content source
    DataSpec(Uri.parse(url)), // ads url will handle preroll
    listOf(url, mediaSource.mediaItem.mediaId), // sample object ID
    DefaultMediaSourceFactory(context)
        .setLocalAdInsertionComponents({ loader }, // use the builder: ImaAdsLoader.Builder
            { view }) // default groupView
        .setServerSideAdInsertionMediaSourceFactory(
            adsSSAIMediaSourceFactory // use the factory: ImaServerSideAdInsertionMediaSource.Factory
        ),
    loader
) { view }
```

So if you want to request ads (like non paid users) use this media source, if not, just keep the original content media source. This is the only wrapper that worked for me to handle different types of sources like Cronet, Hls, Dash, Akamai, Clippable and DRM